# Listener Configuration for Availability Group

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

Apart from the Availability Group Listener, is there any other SQL Server listener object that is configured and is in Active Directory?

The Communication endpoint (which listens on port 5022) needs to be granted connect to the SQL service account and this is in SQL. What other "listener" configuration should there be?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Apart from the Availability Group Listener, is there any other SQL Server listener object that is configured and is in Active Directory?

No. The computer object backing the listener in AD is the only AD object created for AGs and only created when using AD integration.

> The Communication endpoint (which listens on port 5022) needs to be granted connect to the SQL service account and this is in SQL.

Certificates can also be used in place of this.

The service account isn't a listener configuration, nor are the endpoints.

> What other "listener" configuration should there be?

In terms of configuration for the listener, there are the requirements which much be met in order to create the listener - for example, via T-SQL. Outside of that, there are no other changes/items/configurations needed.

Comment: thanks again for your time, patience and willingness to share your expertise on this subject, very much appreciated

Comment: Summarising previous posts which you have very kindly helped on, am I correct then to say that what I need in terms of Active Directory/DNS entries are as follows: 1. Create cluster CNO in AD, 2. Grant 'create/delete computer objects' to the SQL service account, 3. Grant 'create/delete computer objects' to the cluster CNO

Comment: Additionally for the Listener, if prestaging - 1. Add a record in DNS for the listener VNN, 2. Create a listener CNO in AD, 3. Give full control on the listener CNO to the cluster CNO. Is this all correct?

Comment: Lastly, what then is a SQL Listener? I know SQL Server listens on a port which is TCP 1433 by default, but I'm not aware that a SQL Listener needs to be created by the Windows team, different from the AG listener CNO in AD. Are you able to shed some light on what this "SQL Listener" could be please?

Comment: A listener is a way to point to the primary replica of an AG, wherever it goes. The listener is implemented as a network name resource in the cluster (AD Integrated), IP address(es), and associated dns entries. The parts of a listener depend on the type of AG being used. AD Integration with WSFC will require computer objects, this is a function of the cluster. Some options do not, such as distributed network names. The implementation and function are separate.

Comment: thanks again for your time, much appreciated